# Preventing OS fingerprinting

Tags: operating-systems, fingerprint

I am working on a project and I need to hide my Linux OS from nmap or other OS identification tools. I read many articles about TCP/IP stack and changed many properties such as TTL and packet size but it doesn't seem to work and it creates many problems within the machine.

How can I hide my OS from identification or force it to be identified as a Windows machine?

Comment: This depends entirely on how a given program identifies your OS.

Comment: yes exactly, nmap for example depends on tcp/ip packets, in other terms properties of the packets, it's what I read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the settings on your machine, why not send your traffic through another machine?

Use a Windows machine as a proxy and send all traffic through it. If you virtualise the process, you can have many machines, all with different configurations and OSes, and you can switch from one to the other at will.

And if that can work, then why not just use all those disposable VMs as your machines and not proxy at all? Remote into those VMs, do what you need to, and switch as needed.

Comment: the first idea is pretty good, I will try it, thank you, and btw it's a honeypot my solution just so you would know why I m trying hard to hide the os or make it look as a windows one